# how to fetch other app's file and folders access in our app in android?

Tags: android, flutter, file, directory, accessibility

I am using flutter for this , but unable to find any way where we can fetch what files and folder do other apps are using . I have also searched for android but didn't got any absolute answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use [external_path](https://pub.dev/packages/external_path) for fetching all the directories
but if you are targeting android 10+ then you should add

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

permissions.